# Create a property of custom user control using c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a `UserControl` which contains `Text Property`.

`Text Property`:

```
private string _Text;
public string Text
    {
        set 
        {
            _Text= value;
        }
        get 
        {
            return _Text;
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to get `TextValueChanged` event of `Text Property` when I type into `Text Property`. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wpf, first create a different class and create a for Notify property changed 
viewmodelbase class:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IMVVMDockingProperties
    { 
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}
```

then where you are implementing this property just add one more line of code:

```
private string _Text;
public string Text
    {
        set 
        {
            _Text= value;
        }
        get 
        {
            return _Text;
            **OnPropertyChanged("Text");**
        }
    }
```

also if you want to get notified on every character entered event add this to your binding:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Text, **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged**, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: I created UserControl using Windows Form Control Library, and added to ToolBox

Comment: implementation in class remains same.

Answer (score 3):

If it's property and you need to pass old text value/new text value - you should to create your own arguments and delegate like this:

```
public class TextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string PreviousText;
    public string CurrentText;

    public TextChangedEventArgs(string previousText, string currentText)
    {
        PreviousText = previousText;
        CurrentText = currentText;
    }
}

public delegate void TextChangedEventHandler(Object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e);
```

After that you should just check - does any have your event and trigger it:

```
    public event TextChangedEventHandler TextChanged;
    private string _Text;
    public string Text
    {
        set
        {
            var previousText = _Text;

            _Text = value;

            if (TextChanged != null)
            {
                var args = new TextChangedEventArgs(previousText, value);
                TextChanged(this, args);
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _Text;
        }
    }
```

To use this event you should attach it (in constructor of control for example):

```
   TextChanged += TextChangedFunc;
```

And add new func:

```
   void TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
```

Comment: I want to catch the event in this UserControl to do something. What I do?

Comment: Can you understand me. You have WinForms and you have textEdit component? Or you have just text field in class? In first case - you should open designer and find in events "TextChanged'. If second - just use my code.  To attach event add in consructor - revew my answer, I updated it.

Comment: register handler with TextChanged event. `TextChanged += (s,e) => { //do staff}`

Comment: I don't really understand.

Comment: Updated unswer. 1. You create new class with arguments for your event. It means that you can pass to event information that you need (in our case it is new and old values of text). 2. You add  event to your text field. It means that if somebody attached to your event - it will trigger. 3. You attach to your created event (in constructor). So, now when event triggers - you will go to your procedure, that you create in step 4.

Comment: Artem Kulikov, Thank you so much for your help, I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you making an MVVM application? If you install the handy [MvvmLight Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) you can do it as follows:

```
private string _Text;
public string Text
{
    set
    {
        if (_Text != value)
        {
            _Text = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
        }
    }

    get
    {
        return _Text;
    }
}
```

And bind it as follows in your view (XAML):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41817/Implementing-INotifyPropertyChanged